# Countdown timer in python/wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to have countdown as per below image either in python or wxpython (Any other library). I have googled but didn't find the same. I have also checked wxpython but it doesn't have same implementation, however it has gauge but that is not what Im looking for. Can anybody please help me to get it done. Thanks.

[image: Animated Countdown with percentage]

Comment: Does it need to be animated?

Comment: yes, So far I'm able to draw circle with color and also counter but looking for way to get it animated too

Comment: Not sure that wxpython supports that as a implementation. And since I'm running Python3 on this machine I can't test stuff for you, but this might get you on track? http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.piectrl.html

Comment: Another solution would be to create the animation using a GL library and put it inside a frame of wxPython (if possible, I know it's possible with Tkinter and some others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to get what I exactly need after googling and little tweaks. My actual requirement is a countdown (timer) with animation. Below is the code that did the trick(Thanks to Andrea Gavana for wonderful work):

Hope it will help someone else looking for the same.

[SpeedMeter](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/Zipped/SpeedMeter.zip)

My Implementation:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.buttons

import SpeedMeter as SM
from math import pi, sqrt

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "SpeedMeter Demo ;-)",
                         wx.DefaultPosition,
                         size=(400,400),
                         style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE |
                         wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.SpeedWindow = SM.SpeedMeter(panel,
                                          extrastyle=SM.SM_DRAW_HAND |
                                          SM.SM_DRAW_SECTORS |
                                          SM.SM_DRAW_MIDDLE_TEXT |
                                          SM.SM_DRAW_SECONDARY_TICKS |
                                          SM.SM_DRAW_PARTIAL_FILLER |
                                          SM.SM_DRAW_SHADOW
                                          )

        # We Want To Simulate A Clock. Somewhat Tricky, But Did The Job
        self.SpeedWindow.SetAngleRange(pi/2, 5*pi/2)

        intervals = range(0, 13)
        self.SpeedWindow.SetIntervals(intervals)

        colours = [wx.SystemSettings_GetColour(0)]*12
        self.SpeedWindow.SetIntervalColours(colours)

        ticks = [str(interval) for interval in intervals]
        ticks[-1] = ""
        ticks[0] = "12"
        self.SpeedWindow.SetTicks(ticks)
        self.SpeedWindow.SetTicksColour(wx.BLUE)
        self.SpeedWindow.SetTicksFont(wx.Font(11, wx.SCRIPT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, True))
        self.SpeedWindow.SetNumberOfSecondaryTicks(4)

        # Set The Colour For The External Arc        
        self.SpeedWindow.SetArcColour(wx.BLUE)

        self.SpeedWindow.SetHandColour(wx.BLACK)

        self.SpeedWindow.SetMiddleText("0 s")
        self.SpeedWindow.SetMiddleTextColour(wx.RED)

        # We Set The Background Colour Of The SpeedMeter OutSide The Control
        self.SpeedWindow.SetSpeedBackground(wx.WHITE)

        # Set The Colour For The Shadow
        self.SpeedWindow.SetShadowColour(wx.Colour(128, 128, 128))        

        self.SpeedWindow.SetSpeedValue(0.0)

        # These Are Cosmetics For our SpeedMeter Control

        # Create The Timer For The Clock
        self.timer = wx.PyTimer(self.ClockTimer)
        self.currvalue = 0

        bsizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        hsizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
        stattext2 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "A Simple Clock", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        button2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Stop")
        self.stopped = 0
        button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStopClock)
        button2.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("Click To Stop/Resume The Clock"))

        hsizer2.Add(button2, 0, wx.LEFT, 5)
        #hsizer2.Add(stattext2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        #hsizer2.Add(self.helpbuttons[1], 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)

        bsizer2.Add(self.SpeedWindow, 1, wx.EXPAND)        
        bsizer2.Add(hsizer2, 0, wx.EXPAND)        
        panel.SetSizer(bsizer2)
        self.timer.Start(1000)

    def ClockTimer(self):
        if self.currvalue >= 59:
            self.currvalue = 0
        else:
            self.currvalue = self.currvalue + 1

        self.SpeedWindow.SetMiddleText(str(self.currvalue) + " s")            
        self.SpeedWindow.SetSpeedValue(self.currvalue/5.0)


    def OnStopClock(self, event):

        btn = event.GetEventObject()

        if self.stopped == 0:
            self.stopped = 1
            self.timer.Stop()
            btn.SetLabel("Resume")
        else:
            self.stopped = 0
            self.timer.Start()
            btn.SetLabel("Stop")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    #frame.Maximize()

    app.MainLoop()
```